# Get X and Y coordinates from collision in Box2dweb (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, box2dweb

When there is a collision in Box2dweb, this class create some objects. b2ContactListener.prototype.BeginContact

From there I can access a lot of  data with:

```
var a = contact.GetFixtureA().GetUserData();
var b = contact.GetFixtureB().GetUserData();
```

Yet I can't find the way to get the X and Y values of the collision with some seudo code like this.

```
var aColX = contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody().GetPosition().x;
var aColY = contact.GetFixtureA().GetBody().GetPosition().y;
```

What's the right way to get this data from contact.GetFixtureA()? //Object A

Comment: It's hard to find anything considering that this library was last updated 10 years ago

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer.

```
var aColX = contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody().GetTransform().position.x;
var aColY = contact.GetFixtureB().GetBody().GetTransform().position.y;
```